# Does a bounded real function have an analytic continuation

Tags: analytic-functions, real-analysis, analytic-continuation, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Consider the function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where

- $f$ is real-analytic on the open interval $(0,1)$
- $f$ is bounded on the closed interval $[0,1]$ (ie. there is some constant $C$ such that $-C\leq f(x)\leq C$ for $x\in[0,1]$).

Is it true that there is a real-analytic continuation of $f$ to the interval $[-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon]$ for some small positive $\epsilon$? If not, what conditions can be added to make it true?

Suggestions for books (or other references) where I could have learned to answer this myself would also be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest to reask this question on math.stackexchange.com a similar site but with a broader scope. Here I vote to close. 


Comment: While others have provided quite smooth counterexamples, I note that your conditions do not even force $f$ to be continuous at the end-points.

Comment: @quid I wasn't aware of the difference between math.stackexchange and mathoverflow. Now that I've looked that up, I agree, this question would have been better on math.stackexchange. 

Comment: Essex, thanks for the response. No problem, this is a frequent phenomenon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ is real analytic on $(-1,1)$, bounded and continuous on $[-1,1]$, but of course not even one-sided differentiable at the endpoints.  But then Igor's example is one-sided differentiable of all orders at the endpoint $0$, but still not real analytic in any neighborhood of $0$.

Answer (score 5):

What about $e^{-1/x^2}?$

Comment: @quid: I will probably still be cryptic, but you do agree this answers the question as stated, no?


Comment: @quid: I agree that this is not a research question, but the police work gets really tedious, especially when it takes thirty seconds to answer the question. 

Comment: @quid: I probably voted to close about 10 questions today.

Comment: Let me say it like this: if you answer question of which you know they are not really on-topic (it is not like I never do this myself), could you please try to do so in a more helpful/complete way. Otherwise this seems to me to be a loose--loose situation ('we' have the 'noise', of your answer [a comment is at least less noisy], and the questioner still no good answer), which I thus find a bit annoying. [I delete my earlier more direct comments.]  

Comment: @quid: you have a right to your opinion. I don't happen to agree.

Comment: This is perhaps more appropriate for a meta thread but: 1. It is not just a
question of the time it takes to answer it, it is also a question of teaching
people to not expect to receive answers to inappropriate questions. 2. If one
decides to answer it anyway then I think this kind of answer is quite
appropriate. If it really is after all a research level question then this is a
research level answer, the OP should be able to fill in the details.

Comment: @IR: ok, let us agree to disagree. @TE: it's not only that the answer is terse, it is imo in a strict sense *incomplete* (the other one too, btw). How does it address (on whatever level) the second question (for conditions)? Except in such a cryptic way that I'd say 'the obvious ones' is hardly less cryptic. If one wishes to be brief, that's fine; but one could have been almost as brief while being complete. I see no good reason for not doing this.
 